# Argument in recursive function changes itself somehow

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

So, I have to find all possible cycles in not directed graph, that starts (and ends) at chosen vertex.

I have written an algorithm for it in js: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/universome/SZtaL/7/)

But faced very, very weird problem: in my recursive function, argument changes itself somehow! But I dont even touch it! Pls help me, I am suffering with this bug for 16 hours already! :(

I thinkm that this arguments is changed by this code:

```
cycle.push(vertex);
```

But it should not! Becuase in his visibility area the global cycle variable must be overwritten by local one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
var newCycle = cycle;
```

You're not **cloning** it, you're just giving the same object a different name. Try:

```
var newCycle = cycle.slice(0);
```

Comment: You...you've just saved my life!
I guess, I should learn more about assignments in js :)